# no WCF max response message size setting in wshttpbinding?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, response, wshttpbinding

I am surprised to see that no WCF max response message size setting in wshttpbinding? My question is whether there is max response message size setting in wshttpbinding? I am using .Net 3.0 + C# + VSTS 2008.

BTW: I have found max request message size setting and tested it works.

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: George, please rephrase your question as a question. It's not clear what you're asking, or even if you're asking anything at all.

Comment: Thanks John! It is always clear from the other eye (perspective). Thanks again! I have corrected my post, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this means there is no restriction on the size of message you can send.

Basically maxReceivedMessageSize is there to protect your server from DoS attacks using long messages.  There is not the same need for a limit to the size of the response message, as that's under your control.

A client may of course want to set maxReceivedMessageSize to avoid excessively long message from a rogue server.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I think we can choose to whether self-host or IIS host. Currently, I am using self-host, and I think your reply also applies to self-host scenario, correct?

Comment: " also applies to self-host " - yes absolutely.